# How do I import my reading list in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, import, reading-list

I am a heavy Windows 8 reading list user and recently upgraded to 10. I was able to import my favorites into the Edge browser just fine, but can't seem to import or find my reading list?

How do I import it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the Reading List was imported into an application called "Reading List" that is separate from the Reading List in Edge.

Currently it only works in "Tablet" mode, so there may be a slight variation in application resources between "Computer" and "Tablet" modes.